# How do I read my input from text area in react?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to read input from text area once I finish typing. I read somewhere that you need onBlur event handler to achieve this functionality instead of onChange. However when I use onBlur, I am not able to enter my input. Where am I going wrong?

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
class HelloWorld extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            value: '',
        }
    }
    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({value: event.target.value})
        console.log(this.state.value)
    }     
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <h1>Hello World Restaurant</h1>
                <textarea placeholder="Enter name of guest:" onBlur={this.handleChange.bind(this)} value={this.state.value}></textarea>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
ReactDOM.render(<HelloWorld/>,document.getElementById('root'))
```

Comment: Have you read the docs anyway? https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html

Comment: @mike Yes I have read the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing the concept of [controlled component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html) and [uncontrolled component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/uncontrolled-components.html).

If you are using `value` property then you need to use `onChange` method to update the `state` value, otherwise it will become **read-only** (you are controlling the value of textarea by state, so if state will not update whatever you type in textarea will get reset by state value).

If you don't want the `onChange` method then remove the **value property of textarea**, it will allow you to type then inside `onBlur` get the value by `event.target.value`.

Check this example (Uncontrolled Component):

```js
class HelloWorld extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            value: '',
        }
    }
    
    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({value: event.target.value})
    }  
    
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <h1>Hello World Restaurant</h1>
                value: {this.state.value}
                <br/>
                <textarea placeholder="Enter name of guest:" onBlur={this.handleChange.bind(this)}></textarea>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<HelloWorld/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'/>
```

Comment: What if I want to display the entered input in new line, how do I do that?

Comment: didn't get you what you mean by new line? where you want to display the input text ?

Comment: I am getting output like this "values: hello how are" but I want like this to be displayed "values: hello how are" all in new line

Comment: you want "values" in one line then the value of textarea in new line correct ?

Comment: Yeah, how do i achieve this?

Comment: put a break between them, like this: `value: <br/> {this.state.value}`

Answer (score 1):

To add to Mayank's answer,

I will suggest you to make use of controlled input as git gives you more flexibility to use the values later on

You can do that like

```js
class HelloWorld extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            value: '',
        }
    }
    handleBlur() {
        console.log('You finished typing:', this.state.value)
    }
    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({value: event.target.value})
    }  
    
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <h1>Hello World Restaurant</h1>
                value: {this.state.value}
                <br/>
                <textarea placeholder="Enter name of guest:" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} value={this.state.value} onBlur={this.handleBlur.bind(this)}></textarea>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<HelloWorld/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'/>
```